# How to add custom header for every request in swagger json file

Tags: swagger, postman, swagger-ui

I've copy swagger.json file from one of the service and want to import it into Postman collection

Then the problem is I want to add custom API-key in header for every requests.
I've read about `securityDefinitions` but it doesn't seems to work

Let's say it's name is `myCustomAPIKey`, Is there a way that I can add it manually in *swagger's JSON* file ?

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" - what have you tried and how exactly did it not work?

Comment: It's a just a JSON file right, you can just edit it. Take a look at https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Its normal to do it like the following snippet. You create af securityDefinition and then use that definition in the security section.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "API",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "host": "example.com",
  "basePath": "/api",
  "schemes": [
    "http",
    "https"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "myCustomAPIKey": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "myCustomAPIKey",
      "in": "header"
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {
      "myCustomAPIKey": []
    }
  ],
  "paths": {...}
}
```

Its documented here (for version 2) https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/